# Cannot Add an Icon to QML Desktop Application

Tags: qt, window, icons, qml

I'm writing a QML Desktop Application in QtCreator and c++(on Win7).

In my main.cpp, I have loaded the application like this:

```
Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QDeclarativeView view;
    view.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/GenericHostApplicationQML/myMain.qml"));
    view.show();
    menu->load();
    return app.exec();
}
```

and now I want to add an Icon to my application window, so I tried  this:

```
view.setWindowIcon(QIcon("qrc:/qml/GenericHostApplicationQML/content/pics/TXE.ico"));
```

and I'm not getting any error, but while I'm running it, the window has the regular .exe file icon, and not the wanted one. I tried changing the picture, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.0/appicon.html)'s the documentation about how to set your Desktop Qt Application icon.

**Edit**: Also, for the window icon you're setting, be sure that referred image file is actually listed in your application resources (see [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.0/resources.html)).

Comment: Thank you, @TheHuge_,I've read what you wrote and what you linked to, it helped me, but I solved my problem just with:
view.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/qml/GenericHostApplicationQML/content/pics/TXE.ico"));
Tnx again!

Comment: @user1835297 please post this as an answer, and then accept it after a while

Answer (score 0):

In QT 6,
add the png file to the qml.qrc file as below.

```
<file>app.png</file>
```

Then in c++ add this,

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(QStringLiteral(":app.png")));
```